# Mount an ntfs partition two times

Tags: mount, ntfs

I want to mount an ntfs partition on two different mount-points on my Debian. I have already done this with other file systems like vfat or ext4, but I am not able to do it with ntfs:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/mp_0 /tmp/mp_1
mount -t ntfs -umask=000 /dev/sda1 /tmp/mp_o --> everything is till now ok
mount -t ntfs -umask=000 /dev/sda1 /tmp/mp_1 --> ERROR
Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.
The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which
could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
```

Why can't I mount ntfs twice?

*********** Update **********

as far as i understood, ntfs does not provide such a feature, whereby it is not even needed since i can acheive the same effect with

```
mount --bind
```

Thanks

Comment: You could try replacing the second mount with `mount --bind /tmp/mp_0 /tmp/mp_1`.

Comment: @TomHunt thanks. unfortunatlly it's not allowed to mount a ntfs twice or more without binding ;(

Comment: @arashjavan why don't you want to bind? That does exactly what you seem to need. Also, wouldn't making `/tmp/mp_1` a link to `/tmp/mp_0` be enough? Please [edit] your question and tell us what your final objective is. Why do you need top mount the partition twice? This sounds like it might be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101).